# Flash Builder 4.5 debugger terminates | Safari

Tags: flash, debugging, safari, webkit, terminate

So it seems all the major browser vendors are sandboxing the flash plugin, and terminating it after a certain amount of inactivity. This is problematic for developers who connect the Flash Builder Debugger to the browser. If you stand on a breakpoint for more than 45 seconds, it terminates your session.

I've found a config param to change on firefox that disabled this functionality, but i havent found a similar command for Safari/ Webkit / Chrome.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/899/cpsid_89943.html

"To prevent Firefox from terminating plug-ins that it considers unresponsive, set dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs to -1 in about:config. For more information, see Plugin hang detector."

Answer (score 6):

Inactivity resets by browser:

- Chrome
  Pass `--disable-hang-monitor` on the command line.
- Firefox
  Type `about:config` in the adress bar.
  Find `dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs` and set its value to -1.
- Safari
  No configuration switches, use `SafariNoTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to Firefox when I encountered this problem. But I just found this if you dont want to switch browser:

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11457/safarinotimeout/

"SafariNoTimeout is an essential tool for any web developer or a user who has ever experienced an annoying 60 seconds timeout while waiting for a web page. "

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a nightly build of webkit you can enter the following in your command line, then debug in Webkit

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitDisablePluginProcessMessageTimeout YES
```

Now when you launch your debugger pointed to WebKit, it wont terminate the plugin.

Note: You can target Webkit in you Pref - Web Browser - Add New

```
Name: Webkit
Location: /Applications/WebKit.app/Contents/MacOS/WebKit
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has an option to --disable-hang-monitor: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/831/cpsid_83111.html

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I saw this reference [Jack Murphy about Webkit nightly build and how to turn that timeout off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789587/1837991).  So, I thought... hmmm Safari... Webkit.. and I tried the same method.  Didn't work.  So time goes by ... not answers... talk to people about this...  and unsanity says nada... so on a whim I tried it again.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.2 and Safari 6.0.2 and this it works for me

Open console and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitDisablePluginProcessMessageTimeout YES
```