# How to stop Safari from timing out when debugging Flash

Tags: flash, safari, flash-builder

Is there any way to stop Safari (Version 5.1.1 on OS X Lion) from killing flash while I'm in the middle of debugging with Flash Builder 4.5.1?  It's driving me absolutely insane!

Comment: I finally figured out a fix for this... I know this is an old question but you prob still can't debug with safari... so see my answer on the post mentioned in answer 2 below.  IT WORKS!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flash Builder 4.5 debugger terminates | Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478465/flash-builder-4-5-debugger-terminates-safari)

Answer (score 1):

If using Firefox instead of Safari is an option, you can set dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs to to -1 in the about:config page to disable the timeout.

Comment: I can use all browsers, however Safari is much smoother when developing in Flash.  Surely there must be a way to do this in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to: [Flash Builder 4.5 debugger terminates | Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478465/flash-builder-4-5-debugger-terminates-safari)

If Chrome is an option: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/error-plug-unresponsive-google-chrome.html

Specifically for Safari: no configuration switches, use [SafariNoTimeout](http://unsanity.com/haxies/snt), but Requires Mac OS X 10.2 through Mac OS X 10.3.6. And is NOT compatible with Mac OS X 10.6 Leopard.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I'm on OS X Lion (10.7+), so SafariNoTimeout doesn't work.  Still unsolved.

Comment: Same here, so I ended up not using Safari for debugging. Firefox works just fine for my needs.

Comment: unsanity.com is timing out for me... (Seems down) (And it seems to not be an option on any somewhat recent OS X versions....)