# Flash Builder 4.5 debugger timeout with Safari and Mountain Lion (OSX 10.8)

Tags: flash, debugging, safari, flash-builder

I know there a fix for previous versions of the MacOS, is there anything yet for Mountain Lion?

[Flash Builder 4.5 debugger terminates | Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478465/flash-builder-4-5-debugger-terminates-safari)

The Safari answer is there: for Safari - use SafariNoTimeout (from http://www.unsanity.com ) - doesn't run on OSX 10.8

Comment: Contacted unsanity.com to see if they had any plans to make a Mountain Lion version, waiting to hear back.

Comment: Further clarification - I need to run the debugger in Flash Builder and viewing the app on the page with Safari/Chrome/Firefox.  Chrome and Firefox allow you to turn off the time out, but Safari won't with OS10.8.  In a large project, trying to debug and look at variables and use breakpoints is almost useless with the default of 60 seconds before the app fails in the browser.  That is why I'd like this.

Comment: did they ever reply?  This has aggravated the crap out of me for some time now.. +1 on the question and a high five and a gold star.

Comment: They never did - and looking at their blog and blog entries, they're hurting.  Asked for money up front - $15 - for some of their apps to help cover costs to upgrade for Lion and nothing for over a year.  Probably won't see anything - which is sad.

Comment: ha ha ha yaay yaay yaay on a whim i tried something and I got it.....  wanna know how???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, so I saw this reference about Webkit nightly build and how to turn that timeout off.  So, I thought... hmmm Safari... Webkit.. and I tried the same method.  Didn't work.  So time goes by ... not answers... talk to you and unsanity says nada... so on a whim I tried it again.

IT WORKS IT WORKS IT WORKS

open console and type:

defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitDisablePluginProcessMessageTimeout YES

Comment: nice - too bad you didn't figure this out a couple days ago - I had a 50 point bounty that got wasted....